# Overriding method of a delegateClass in child class in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, delegates, tableview

I have a class `HomeViewController` which extends `SectionController`. I'm using `sectionController` as a property in `HomeViewController`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SectionsController *sectionController
```

and setting delegate and `datasource` in `viewDidLoad` of `HomeViewController` as:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self.sectionController;
self.tableView.dataSource = self.sectionController;
```

`SectionController` defines some `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods:

```
(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{    
}

(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
 }

(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
}
```

`SectionController` is my base class and is extended by many more classes. I don't wish to write my logic in `SectionController` class, rather it is more convenient if I can override these `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods in `HomeViewController` itself.

Is there a way to override these methods?

Comment: If HomeViewController is a subclass of SectionController, why does it have a reference to some other instance of a SectionController?  You should set the delegate to `self` then you can implement whatever methods you want in the subclass

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11. This seems like an architecture problem.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 i agree with you but HomeViewController is not a subclass of SectionController, rather it uses SectionController as a property... sorry for any misunderstanding which i might have created while posting the question..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just override these methods in your HomeViewController Class. Just define same methods in .m file and if you want to use the code of your super class too then do like this way:

```
    (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
[super scrollViewDidEndDragging:scrollView willDecelerate:decelerate];
//Do your class specific things
    }
```

Comment: I tried overriding this way, but still on scrolling methods of my baseclass are called instead of  overriden methods.